# Is there a difference between マジ and 本当?

Tags: words

Is there a difference betweenマジand 本当？　I know that both terms mean really.

Comment: Also related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4786/1628

Comment: My question is a duplicate. May I delete it?

Comment: @JACK Usually we don't delete duplicate questions, since they might be able to help future users find the existing answers they need.  You can if you want to, though.

Comment: I will leave it as a contribution to the knowledge base.